# Visual Studio hangs, Microsoft.Alm.Shared.Remoting.RemoteContainer, hugs CPU

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, freeze

In Visual Studio 2017 freezes when I reload my solution. 
When I look the task manager I can see that the process Microsoft.Alm.Shared.Remoting.RemoteContainer.dll (32 bit) is hugging all my cores (see screen shoot). I tried to disable CodeLens, restart VS, and turn on CodeLens bit the problem persists.
[image]

I am using Visual Studio 2017 professional 15.5.2
My OS is Windows 10 version 1709 build 16299.15.

I can see that this [problem](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807273/microsoft-alm-shared-remoting-remotecontainer-high-cpu) was reported in 2013 and does not seem to have been fixed.

Should I just turn off CodeLens since I am only programming C++.

Update: I turned off CodeLense and the problem persists.

Update2: I tried to run a performance analysis as suggested by magicandre1981 (thank you!) but unfortunately there does not seem to be any debug symbols for the .dll on the Microsoft's Symbol server. I did load the Symbols.

[image]

Comment: use [Windows Performance Toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42349119/1466046) to analyze the CPU usage of the process.

Comment: symbols are laoded fine. use mouse to seelct the part in the graph before "TRACE Rundown", do a rightclick and select "Filter to selection". The n/a shows the usage of the rundown where no stacks are captured, at this time the debug symbols get generated and system data are merged into the final ETl file. to be able to load symbols.

Comment: have you got it working or do you need help?

Comment: Could not find out how to get tge stack trace yet.

Comment: share the zipped (to reduce file size to up- and download) ETL + nGENPDB folder and I'll take a look at it.