# How do I analyze a mini dump (.dmp) file from another server to find out what caused the w3wp worker process to hang and throttle the CPU?

Tags: iis, windows-10, cpu-usage, dump

I have debugdiag and windbg on my windows 10 machine. DebugDiag spits out an error when I try to analyze the dmp file. WinDbg doesn't seem to be giving me much of anything (I'm no expert by any means). Is there something else I should be using to analyze what could be the offender in the process hang?

Comment: Open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and share the dumps with Microsoft.

Comment: use [Windows Performance Toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42349119/1466046) to analyze [CPU usage](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis) / [hang](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-43-WPT-Wait-Analysis)