# TCP Socket High CPU/Memory usage after 5mins

Tags: c#, sockets, memory-leaks, cpu-usage, tcpclient

I'm building a server app that accepts incoming TCP connections. (roughly 300 unique clients). It's important to note that I do not have control over the clients.

I have found that some of the connecting clients remain idle for quite some time after making the initial connection and sending the first status update. When they remain idle for over 5 mins the application's CPU usage jumps to over 90% and remains there.

To address this issue I built in a cancellation token that is triggered after 4 mins. This allows me to kill the connection. The client then detects this and reconnects about a minute later. This solves the high CPU usage issue, but has the side effect of high memory usage, there seems to be a memory leak. I suspect the resources is being held by the previous socket object.

I have a client object that contains the socket connection and information about the connected client. It also manages the incoming messages. There is also a manager class which accepts the incoming connections. It then creates the client object, assigns the socket to it and adds the client object to a concurrent dictionary. Every 10 seconds it checks the dictionary for clients that have been set to _closeConnection = true and calls their dispose method.

Here is the some of client object code:

```
public void StartCommunication()
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[75]);
            while (IsConnected)
            {
                try
                {
                    // This is where I suspect the memory leak is originating - this call I suspect is not properly cleaned up when the object is diposed
                    var result = await SocketTaskExtensions.ReceiveAsync(ClientConnection.Client, buffer, SocketFlags.None).WithCancellation(cts.Token);

                    if (result > 0)
                    {
                        var message = new ClientMessage(buffer.Array, true);
                        if(message.IsValid)
                            HandleClientMessage(message);
                    }
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    _closeConnection = true;
                    DisconnectReason = "Client has not reported in 4 mins";
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    _closeConnection = true;
                    DisconnectReason = "Error during receive opperation";
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _closeConnection = true;
            cts.Cancel();
            // Explicitly kill the underlying socket
            if (UnitConnection.Client != null)
            {
                UnitConnection.Client.Close();
            }

            UnitConnection.Close();
            cts.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Task Extension Method:

```
public static async Task<T> WithCancellation<T>(this Task<T> task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        using (cancellationToken.Register(s => ((TaskCompletionSource<bool>)s).TrySetResult(true), tcs))
        {
            if (task != await Task.WhenAny(task, tcs.Task))
            {
                throw new OperationCanceledException(cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        return task.Result;
    }
```

Mananger Code:

```
    public bool StartListener()
    {
        _listener = new TcpListenerEx(IPAddress.Any, Convert.ToInt32(_serverPort));
        _listener.Start();
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (_maintainConnection) // <--- boolean flag to exit loop
            {
                try
                {
                    HandleClientConnection(await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //<snip>
                }
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    private void HandleClientConnection(TcpClient client)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                // Create new Coms object
                var client = new ClientComsAsync();
                client.ClientConnection = client;
                // Start client communication
                client.StartCommunication();

                //_clients is the ConcurrentDictionary

                ClientComsAsync existingClient;
                if (_clients.TryGetValue(client.ClientName, out existingClient) && existingClient != null)
                {
                    if (existingClient.IsConnected)
                        existingClient.SendHeatbeat();
                    if (!existingClient.IsConnected)
                    {
                        // Call Dispose on existing client
                        CleanUpClient(existingClient, "Reconnected with new connection");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //<snip>
            }
            finally
            {
                //<snip>
            }
        });
    }

    private void CleanUpClient(ClientComsAsync client, string reason)
    {
        ClientComsAsync _client;
        _units.TryRemove(client.ClientName, out _client);
        if (_client != null)
        {
            _client.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This question seems to better fit on to the [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) site. As your code is working but you have performance issues

Comment: [analyze CPU usage with Windows Performance Toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42349119/1466046) maybe it shows wich call is causing it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I know what is causing the high CPU usage. Its the ReceiveAsync call that waits too long for a response. That is why I'm canceling it with the token, but then I get memory leaks. I want to know how to deal with the leak.

Answer (score 1):

> When they remain idle for over 5 mins the application's CPU usage jumps to over 90% and remains there.
>
> To address this issue I built in a cancellation token that is triggered after 4 mins.

The proper response is to solve the high CPU usage problem.

Looks to me like it's here:

```
while (IsConnected)
{
  try
  {
    var result = await SocketTaskExtensions.ReceiveAsync(ClientConnection.Client, buffer, SocketFlags.None);

    if (result > 0)
    {
      ...
    }
  }
  catch ...
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Sockets are weird, and dealing with raw TCP/IP sockets is quite difficult to do correctly. On a side note, I always encourage devs to use something more standard like HTTP or WebSockets, but in this case you don't control the clients, so that's not an option.

Specifically, your code is not handling the case where `result == 0`. If the client devices gracefully closed their socket, you'd see a `result` of `0`, immediately loop back and keep getting a `result` of `0` - a tight loop that uses up CPU.

This is, of course, assuming that `IsConnected` remains `true`. And that may be possible...

You don't show where `IsConnected` is set in your code, but I suspect it's in the error handling after sending the heartbeat message. So here's why that may not work as expected... I suspect that the client devices are closing their sending stream (your receiving stream) while keeping their receiving stream (your sending stream) open. This is one way to shut down a socket, sometimes considered "more polite" because it allows the other side to continue sending data even though this side is done sending. (This is from the client device perspective, so the "other side" is your code, and "this side" is the client device).

And this is perfectly legal socket-wise because each connected socket is *two* streams, not one, each of which can be independently closed. If this happens, your heartbeats will still be send and received without error (and likely just silently discarded by the client device), `IsConnected` will remain `true`, and the read loop will become synchronous and eat up your CPU.

To resolve, add a check for `result == 0` in your read loop and clean up the client just the same as if a heartbeat failed to send.