# Visual Studio build analysis with Windows Performance Recorder shows a very weird behaviour

Tags: performance, build, msbuild, wpr

In database we are used to read the [Wait Time Analysis](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/32184/wait-time-analysis) but Microsoft Windows offer a similar tool ([Windows Performance Recorder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/windows-performance-recorder) / [Xperf](https://systemscenter.ru/wpt.en/html/1108c0ba-d5a4-4f44-82a4-9c077008a9e7.htm)) to understand what is the bottleneck of our system.

WPR is a complex but very interesting tool and monitoring a build I found out a couple of stuffs which I wouldn't have expected:

- **devenv.exe** takes **the greatest part** of the CPU time (why? I would have expected msbuild.exe)
- **vbcscompiler.exe** takes a lot of CPU time too (same comment as before)
- most of CPU time used from devenv.exe seems to be in context switches (?!?!?!?!) related to message queues handling

I have Visual Studio 2019 v16.9.2 with Resharper 2021.1.1
Can someone help me to interpret such a similar behaviour?

Comment: post more details and the stack of the devenv.exe/vbcscompiler.exe

Comment: @magicandre1981: how do I take the stack?

Comment: any updates on this? With wpr -start CPU and later wpr -stop C:\result.etl it includes stacks. Load symbols in WPA and [expand stack to see what both are doing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42349119/1466046)